# Filemaker ExecuteSQL isn't working as expected

Tags: filemaker

I'm using the following line to get the data using `ExecuteSQL`

```
ExecuteSQL("SELECT name, Replace(description, '  ', '__') from event");
```

But it gives the output as `?` which means invalid sql in Filemaker.
If I try the query like below it is working fine.

```
ExecuteSQL("SELECT name, description from event");
```

I don't understand why it is not working. Does Filemaker support `Replace` function of SQL or any error in the code?

Can someone help.

Answer (score 1):

I believe, "replace" is not supported in Filemaker SQL. I can not find it anywhere in the reference.

Comment: Is there any alternate ways?

Comment: Not in Filemaker SQL. You will have to take the result back to FileMaker and use "Substitute". The easier method will be to create another calculation filed in  FileMaker set to your substitute(description) and use that field in SQL